# Why does SML not recognize certain types unless I put it in a variable?

Tags: sml

I have the following type:

```
datatype pattern = Wildcard
         | Variable of string
         | UnitP
         | ConstP of int
         | TupleP of pattern list
         | ConstructorP of string * pattern
```

I am trying to create a function that accepts this type (simplified example):

```
fun check_pat p =   
     case p of
        Wildcard          => 1
      | Variable x        => 2
      | TupleP ps         => 3
      | ConstructorP(_,p) => 4
      | _                 => 5
```

but get an error when I call it with TupleP like so:

```
check_pat TupleP[Variable "x",Variable "xx"];
```

Error:

```
stdIn:3.1-3.46 Error: operator and operand do not agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: pattern
  operand:         pattern list -> pattern
  in expression:
    check_pat2 TupleP
```

But if I set this TupleP type to a variable and call it with that variable I am able to get the intended result. Could anyone let me know why this is the case?

```
 val x = TupleP[Variable "x",Variable "xx"];
 check_pat x;
 val it = 3 : int
```

Comment: SML interprets `check_pat TupleP[Variable "x",Variable "xx"];` as `(check_pat TupleP) [Variable "x",Variable "xx"];` which is obviously something you do not want.  But `check_pat (TupleP [Variable "x",Variable "xx"]);` should work fine.

Comment: The error message basically says that `TupleP` is something that produces a `pattern` from a `pattern list` (i.e., `pattern list -> pattern`) whereas `check_pat` expects a `pattern`.

Comment: Also to enhance readability, I suggest you integrate pattern matching in your function definition instead of using `case`, i.e., write `fun check_pat Wildcard = 1 | check_pat (Variable _) = 2 | ...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in comments, this:

```
check_pat TupleP[Variable "x",Variable "xx"]
```

parses as this:

```
(check_pat TupleP) [Variable "x",Variable "xx"]
```

rather than what you likely intended:

```
check_pat (TupleP [Variable "x",Variable "xx"])
```

Assigning `TupleP [Variable "x",Variable "xx"]` to `x` and then calling `check_pat x` also ensures that `check_pat` is called correctly.